# Prevent modulating color of specific child sprites in godot

Tags: godot

Updated: I had a hacky way to fix this in the answers below, but @Theraots answer is the proper way to go about it.

I am creating a game with fish.

In order to modularize my project, I decided to make a base `Fish` scene and use an instance of it for my `FishPlayer` and `School` scenes. This way I can simply use a base `Fish` in other areas in my game.

[image: Base Fish Scene]

In my `FishPlayer` scene, I would like to add color to my fish which I do by using the `modulate` property in CanvasItem. However, the only problem with this is that it changes the color of the `CPUParticles2D` of my base `Fish` scene. The same thing happens as well in the `FishSchool` scene.

[image: Particles are now orange/brown]

So, the end goal here is to keep the original particles color of the base `Fish` scene while in a new scene allowing color modulation of the rest of the base fish.

I've been messing with the shaders of the CPUParticles in hopes that it would prevent the parent instance from changing it but does not work in my case. Any ideas of what I'm missing here?

Here's a fix that I read about, but didn't work in my case: [link](https://godotengine.org/qa/82029/random-beginner-question-white-black-color-modulated-sprite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context menu of the scene tree on the scene where you instance the fish… Select Editable children. Then you will have access to the child nodes of the fish (while it is still an instance of that scene), so you can use modulate only on the nodes you want, instead of having to use modulate on the root of that scene.

Answer (score 1):

While [Thereaot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73175907/7571258) certainly works, editable children clutter the scene tree and break *encapsulation*. You create a dependency to the internal structure of the `Fish` scene. If you later need to change that structure, this dependency may break. This can be a problem in complex scenes.

As an alternative, you could add a new `fish_color` property to the root node of the `Fish` scene. Attach a script to the root node, which will be named `Fish.gd`.

**Fish.gd**

```py
# Inserted by the editor (might be different if your root node has another type)
extends Sprite2D

# Define our property
@export var fish_color = Color( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 )

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    # Set the sprite's modulate color according to the fish_color property
    # $Name is a shortcut for get_node("Name")
    ($Body as Sprite2D).modulate = fish_color
    ($Tail as Sprite2D).modulate = fish_color
```

Save the script. In your FishPlayer scene, when you select the Fish in the scene tree, you should now see the new property `Fish Color` in the inspector, typically at the top of all properties. You can now use that instead of the `Modulate` color to define the fish color.

Answer (score 0):

The fix I ended up implementing isn't pretty, but the easiest is to grab the individual sprite nodes and modulate them
[image]